# Массив байтов в строку на golang

Tags: golang

Имеется массив байтов вида `array := [104 0 101 0 108 0 108 0 111 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.
Как перевести его в строку, чтобы она была равна видимым его символам (т.е. `string(array[:]) == "hello"`)?

Печатается массив после приведения в строку верно, тоесть видно что hello, но если узнать длину строки то она составляет длину исходного массива = 16. strings.StripSpace не помогает

Comment: источник массива записывает байты (8-бит) как 16-бит слово. Распечатка "кажется правильной" потому что 0x00 байт просто это ASCII NULL так что он просто не видим. или чинить источник или вам в ручную наверно нужно пройтись по массиву убрать нулевые байты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример https://play.golang.org/p/x4GlQmLaHx3

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var array = []byte{104, 0, 101, 0, 108, 0, 108, 0, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

func main() {
    new_array := make([]byte, 0, len(array))
    for _, b := range array {
        if b == 0 {
            continue
        }
        new_array = append(new_array, b)
    }
    // 5 - ожидаемая длинна
    fmt.Println(len(new_array))
    // строка без 0x00
    fmt.Println(string(new_array))
}
```

более корректно было бы так https://play.golang.org/p/cwkXvO_TXH- тк источник это little-endian utf16:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf16"
)

var array = []byte{104, 0, 101, 0, 108, 0, 108, 0, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

func main() {
    if (len(array) & 1) == 1 {
        fmt.Println("длинна массива должна быть чётной")
        return
    }

    words := make([]uint16, 0, len(array)/2)

    // пары байт в uint16
    for i := 0; i < len(array); i += 2 {
        a := binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(array[i:])
        if int(a) == 0 {
            continue
        }
        words = append(words, a)
    }

    // uint16 в руны
    runes := utf16.Decode(words)

    // руны в строку
    fmt.Println(string(runes))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func btos(c []byte) string {
    n := 0
    for _, b := range c {
        if b == 0 {
            continue
        }
        c[n] = b
        n++
    }
    return string(c[:n])
}
```

так думаю будет экономичнее

Comment: наверняка. откуда такая странная строка? такое ощущение что это little-endian utf16

Comment: @biosckon это название модуля dll из функции `windows.MustLoadDLL("Psapi.dll").MustFindProc("GetModuleBaseNameW")`

Comment: А тогда точно так и есть это [utf16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381407.aspx). Если быть очень педантичным то правильно было бы пройтись по массиву вот этой `binary.LittleEndian.Uint16()` функцией и далее https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/#Decode. Ну или что-то в этом духе.